# A hack to write to 32-bit directories from 64-bit MSI package in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Is there any solution to write files to 32-bit directories from 64-bit MSI package in **WiX-toolset**

Comment: 64-bit packages can write to 32-bit directories. The reverse is not true.

Comment: i want to write files to SystemFolder from 64bit package, can you provide a code sample please ?

Answer (score -1):

As you all know that 64-bit MSI packages cannot write to 32-bit directories. so we need separate MSIs for 32-bit and 64-bit.

***My solution :***

I came up with hack to copy files to 32-bit directories from 64-bit MSI package :

```
        <!--"System64Folder"-->
        <Directory Id="System64Folder">
                <Component Id="text1_comp" Guid="PUTYOURGUIDHERE" Win64="yes">
                    <File Source=".\SetupFiles\textFile.txt" Id="textFile1" KeyPath="yes" />
                </Component>
        </Directory>
        <!--"System32Folder"-->
        <Directory Id="WindowsFolder">
            <Directory Id="SystemFolder_x86" Name="SysWOW64">
                <Component Id="text2_comp" Guid="PUTYOURGUIDHERE" Win64="yes">
                    <File Source=".\SetupFiles\textFile.txt" Id="textFile2" KeyPath="yes" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
```

As you can see, the idea is to reference the **WindowsFolder** then reference **SysWOW64**.
This way our file "textFile.txt" will copied to both **System32** and **SysWOW64** folders.